# php - how to add data in array with a loop

Tags: php, arrays

how to add data in array with a loop

**example array required**

```
$get_id = array(
array('id' => '1', 'updated' => '2012-08-11T04:08:53+01:00'));
```

**data required to add in the array**

```
 ID
-----
1
2
3
4
```

please note that key is important in this case

**output should be like**

```
$get_id = array(
array('id' => '1', 'updated' => '2012-08-11T04:08:53+01:00'),
array('id' => '2', 'updated' => '2012-08-11T04:08:53+01:00'),
array('id' => '3', 'updated' => '2012-08-11T04:08:53+01:00'),
array('id' => '4', 'updated' => '2012-08-11T04:08:53+01:00')
);
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (array('1', '2', '3', '4') as $id) {
  $get_id[] = array('id' => $id, 'updated' => '2012-08-11T04:08:53+01:00');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$get_id = array(
  array('id' => '1', 'updated' => '2012-08-11T04:08:53+01:00')
);

$ids = Array('2', '3', '4');

foreach ($ids as $id) {
  $get_id[] = array('id' => $id, 'updated' => '...');
}
```